# Зачем нужны столбцы updated_at и created_at?

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2, yii, миграция

Разбираюсь с `Yii2`, и заметил, что у многих проектов в миграциях есть поля `updated_at` и `created_at`. Вот, например, строки из миграции проекта `yiipowered` для таблицы `user` (https://github.com/samdark/yiipowered/blob/master/migrations/m170122_185806_init.php#L28):

```
'created_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
'updated_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
```

Вопрос - нужно ли добавлять эти поля для своих таблиц, если у меня в проекте, например, ведется логирование всех действий?

Получается, что если добавлю эти поля - получится дублирование информации (запись в логах и в строке `created_at`/`updated_at`)...

Вы бы стали добавлять эти поля, будь вы на моем месте? Если да, то какие плюсы дает такой подход?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавлять или нет - решать вам. В целом `created_at` заполняется временной меткой когда запись была сделана, `updated_at` - когда обновлена последний раз. Если вам не нужна инфа в таблицах - не добавляйте их

Comment: Спасибо. Хотел уточнить - а как вы бы сделали на практике? Стали бы добавлять эти поля при наличии таблицы с логами? Интересует конкретно ваше мнение, как человека, который имеет довольно большой (как мне кажется) опыт в программировании.

Comment: Не стал бы добавлять. У нас как раз есть очень большой проект на Yii2. Есть как раз логирование, как подробное, так и для некоторых сущностей чуть изменённое. В них мы записываем всё, что нам нужно, в остальных 70-ти таблицах соответственно ни одного поля с created_at, update_at и created_by, updated_by  нет